# Told About Something

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, verbs

I want to say that my waiter told me about Japanese restaurants or taught me info about them. I was thinking that I might just try `フュージョンは　日本の食堂を　教えました。` But that would mean the waiter taught Japanese restaurants to me wouldn't it? I would like to say that he told me about something? How do I say "about" something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is フュージョン?  Is that the waiter's name?

Comment: @istrasci "Fusion"? "Fyu-jon" 「フュージョン」.

Comment: @AJFarmar:  I'm aware that it is katakana for "Fusion".  What I'm not aware of it was that is in relation to the example sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I would like to point out is that `教えりました` is fundamentally wrong. I think you were looking for `教えました` (Remember that 教える is 一段｛いちだん｝ or "weak" verb).

In this case however, I think you would like to express gratitude for the person who taught you and thus stay polite. I would reach for either the active `教えてもらう` or passive `教えてくれる` depending on where you want to put the emphasis.

To express `about` the easiest is probably to use `について`.

Thus something along the lines of :

- `フージョンは（私に）和食のレストランについて教えてくれた・教えてくれました。`
- `（私は）フージョンに和食のレストランについて教えてもらった・教えてもらいました。`

Should do just fine. Note that I used `レストラン` instead of `食堂` because the latter, at least in my opinion carries a notion of "canteen", thus a low-end place. Feel free to modify that part !

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I see the issue with my usage of the verb there. It has been a long day. I will edit that in the original post for clarity. I notice that you use 和食の　instead of 日本の and I believe what you are saying means restaurants that serve Japanese food. I mean to say restaurants in Japan. So which would be better? And I am not familiar with this active vs passive form. Would it still be alright to use 教えました?

Comment: 和食 does mean Japanese restaurants. In this instance instead of 和食のレストラン、 using `日本にあるレストラン` would mean restaurants in Japan.

Comment: "和食 does mean Japanese restaurants." Really? I thought it meant Japanese food. "日本にあるレストラン" 日本のレストラン would be fine, too

Comment: Yes 和食 is japanese food, or japanese cuisine. For example, in my 食堂, we often have a choice of either 和食 or 洋食, a.k.a Japanese style lunch or western-style lunch.

Comment: Could I also use `について` when saying that someone talked about something? What other verbs can I use it with?

Comment: Yes you can : 映画について話しましょう is a valid sentence for example. If you want a more definitve answer, please open a new question :)